# PyQtGraph - how do I close a plot window/close all plot windows?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I tried pg.close() but that didn't work, couldn't find it in the manual. I produce plots in a loop, so I'd like to close them all at the end of each loop (instead it pops a new window open until my computer goes nuts).

Answer (score 3):

All Qt widgets have a [`close`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close) method.

And you can close all windows using [`QApplication.closeAllWindows`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#closeAllWindows).

Comment: That's what I thought- although strangely this just leaves me with blank windows instead of destroying them!

Comment: If you close the only widget inside a window, then yes, you would be left with an empty window. Make sure you are calling `close()` on the window itself.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue myself and after reading through the [pyqtgraph source code](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/__init__.py), found out the window needed to be closed along with the plot itself. For example, `pg.close()` to close the plot and `pg.win.close()` to close the window containing the plot.

Answer (score 1):

The code shown below has a exit method.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time
import sys

class guiThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.status=True
        self.range=100

        #Add exit button connect and define a exit function like self.stop
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.stop)

        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Example")
        self.win.resize(500,400)
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
        self.px = self.win.addPlot(title="X plot")
        self.ckx = self.px.plot(pen='y')
        self.cdx = self.px.plot(pen='r')
        self.px.setXRange(0, self.range)
        self.px.setYRange(-180, 180)
        self.px.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateplot)
        self.timer.start(0.001)
        self.kx=np.zeros(self.range)
        self.dx=np.zeros(self.range)
    def updateplot(self):
        self.ckx.setData(self.kx)
        self.cdx.setData(self.dx)
    def append(self,sin):
        self.kx=np.roll(self.kx,-1)
        self.kx[-1]=sin[0]
        self.dx=np.roll(self.dx,-1)
        self.dx[-1]=int(sin[1])
    def stop(self):
        print "Exit" #exiy function
        self.status=False
        sys.exit()
    def run(self):
        print "run"
        while self.status:
            sin=np.random.randint(-180,180,2)
            print sin
            self.append(sin) 
            time.sleep(0.01)
```