# How to close windows in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I want to close all of my pyqtgraph widgets. I followed the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444036/pyqtgraph-how-do-i-close-a-plot-window-close-all-plot-windows), but they didn't work. Here's my code

```
def makeWindows(amp, title):
    WYSIZE = 800
    WXSIZE = 800
    XSIZE = 200
    YSIZE = 200
    TSIZE = 100
    STEPS = np.array([0.0, 0.25, 0.5,.75, 1.0])

    first = "00007F"
    blue = "007FFF"
    cyan = "7FFF7F"
    yellow = "FF7F00"
    red = "7F0000"


    win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    win.resize(WXSIZE, WYSIZE)
    CLRS = [first,blue, cyan, yellow, red]

    for i,item in enumerate(CLRS):
        CLRS[i] = list(ord(c) for c in item.decode('hex')) 
        CLRS[i].append(255)

    clrmp = pg.ColorMap(STEPS, np.array( CLRS))


    lut = clrmp.getLookupTable()

    plt = pg.PlotItem(labels={'bottom': ('samples', 'm'), 'left': ('stuff', 'm')}, title = title)
    plt.setAspectLocked(False)
    imv = pg.ImageView(view = plt)
    win.setCentralWidget(imv)
    #imv.setLevels(3,6)
    imv.ui.histogram.gradient.setColorMap(clrmp)
    imv.setImage(amp)
    win.show()

    return win, imv


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])


    win1, imv1 = makeWindows(amp, "amp")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):            
            status = QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()

            #sys.exit(status)
            imv1.close()
            win1.close()
            app.closeAllWindows()

main()
```

After I execute this window, all of the windows should be closed, but they are not. I'm not even getting the image to close.

Thanks for your help

UPDATE:

My original intention was to create a way to allow the user to close all windows when they inserted a keyboard interrupt (ctrl-c)

I added the following function

```
def close_all():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    app.closeAllWindows()
```

and added the following lines towards the end of makeWindows

```
sh = QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"),imv,None, close_all)
sh.setContext(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
```

This makes it so that anytime a user presses Ctrl+c when a window is in focus, it closes all of the windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `QApplication.exec_()` does not return--it blocks until the application has exited (in this case, the application exits when you close the window). So the lines that would close the window are not called until after you have already closed it.

Comment: is there a way to interrupt QApplication.exec? Do i need to start a background thread beforehand that can send QApplication.quit() when I'm ready for it to end?

Comment: Qt is an event-based framework. You need either user input or a timer to trigger callbacks while the application is running. Perhaps you should explain more of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I would like to have the keyboard interrupt shut down all of the graphs. is there some documentation or reference I can look at that would show how to shut it down?

Comment: If the graph windows are in focus, then they will be responsible for catching keys and you can just create a global shortcut:
`sh = QtGui.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("Ctrl+C"), window);
 sh.setContext(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationShortcut)`.
If the console is in focus, then it might be very difficult to catch a keyboard interrupt.